# SSIS Deployment: Connection Issue

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis

I am facing an issue while deploying my SSIS packages to a target machine.

I have done the deployment through an indirect XML configuration. I use one parent package which invokes all the other child packages in loading a data warehouse. Child packages acquire the database connections via a parent package variable. Thus an isolated child package is not executable.

In this setup the flow works perfectly in my development machine. But when I try to deploy it to another one some packages run and populate the tables while others with the same configurations fail. I have made the "Delay Validation" property to true in all the child packages as well.

Follwing are the errors I get in order:

**Error 17  Validation error. Extract and Populate Data to DimRetailer: DimRetailer: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".   DimRetailer.dtsx    0   0**

**Error 18  Validation error. Extract and Populate Data to DimRetailer: Extract and Populate Data to DimRetailer: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Con_XONTRDDATAMART_OLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.     DimRetailer.dtsx    0   0**

**Error 19  Validation error. DimRetailer Connection manager "Con_XONTRDDATAMART_OLEDB": SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified".   DimRetailer.dtsx    0   0**

**Error 20  Validation error. Extract and Populate Data to DimRetailer Expire Old SCD2 Rows [617]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Con_XONTRDDATAMART_OLEDB" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.    DimRetailer.dtsx    0   0**

What I can not realize is why some packages run alright while others fail which share the same connections.

Additionally, the final deployment will be on a server with a 64 bit OS, are there any steps I should specifically take to make the deployment run smoothly?

Thank you very much for any contribution, in advance.

Comment: Are all connections from failing packages used in other packages also?

Comment: Hi @FilipPopović, thanks for the comment. Sorry for my late response. Yes it is the same connection which is shared among all the packages. Some other interesting feature I noticed is when a package stops due to some other error, some packages in the sequence container stops giving the above error.

Comment: Do You use ExecutoOutOfProcess=true? Try with false. Is your target machine 64-bit? If so, install both 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC drivers or ensure that each package runs in either 32bit or 64bit mode.

Comment: Please read while thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/86e4071d-e018-4618-91f1-08016bbc6391/ it might be of interest to You

Comment: Thanks @FilipPopović I will try out what you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I have a setup similar to yours. However, what i share to child packages is a connection string. It might be worth a try if you are still facing the same issue